# How to import a different stylesheet per layout in nuxt3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

Nuxt3 is out and there are some things that are not quite clear in the docs and there are limited resources since the framework is so new.

I know how to globally import CSS via the `nuxt.config.js` file but I want to import CSS per layout.

I have in the `layouts` folder a `default.vue` layout with the following code. This does not work. What would be a way to accomplish this so that if the user lands on a page using the layout `default.vue` only a specific stylesheet would be used? In addition, is there a way to use an if statement based on the route inside of useHead?

The way it looks right now, the CSS needs to be imported into the page rather than the layout but it would be handy to be able to import the CSS into the layout since it‘s a wrapper around the page.

```js
<script setup>
useHead({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      href: '@/assets/main.css'
    }
  ]
})
</script>


<template>
  <AppHeader />
  <slot />
  <AppFooter />
</template>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but did you try importing the css files in the `style` part of the layout ? you can add a `style` tag and have it import a css as `@import '~/assets/main.css'`

Comment: Yea it's confusing because of the component hierarchy, it looks like the best way is to use `useHead({ style: '/* ... */'})`. With that you can change the style per page. You can also add a body class or html class with `useHead({ htmlAttrs: { class: 'some-class } })`